# Table height fix not working with bootstrap-style percentage layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout, css-tables

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I noticed an odd effect when changing a fluid layout to `display:table` and table-cell. (as described [here](http://www.codelord.net/2013/11/18/css-tip-divs-with-equal-dynamic-heights/), [here](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/), shown [here](http://codepen.io/mariemosley/pen/be5a044df9d23b8a1cee9dc8f2fd2f06).

Try to add display:table and table-cell cells to an existing fluid layout, and the row scrunches up, and actually doesn't expand height. As an example, if you go to http://odetocode.github.io/bootstrap-samples/samples/bootstrap-layout.html and check all stylesheet checkboxes at top, then add a couple rules to selectors in inspector:

`.row { display:table-row;}`

`.row >div {display:table-cell;}`

and add a bit of content to one of the cells, you will see that it actually doesn't expand the height, and oddly enough adding display:table or table-row actually makes the row less wide, for some reason?

Am i seeing some undocumented feature of table css, or is something about bootstrap's styling just incompatible with this type of dynamic height fix?

[image: Table height fix not working with bootstrap-style percentage layout]

Answer (score -1):

Try: `.row > div {display:table-cell;float:none}`

The table-cell won't work properly on an element that's floated.

Comment: Why not? Also - that float is built into Bootstrap, apparently for responsive collapsing?

Comment: The float doesn't have anything to do with the responsive; the width in percentage it what does it.

The float makes divs sit next to each other on the same line, because divs are block-level elements. But table cells are inline elements, so they'll sit next to each other without a float as long as you use the right **col-sm-*** classes to add up to 12.